# Console displays Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function, everything else works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Short code example: http://jsfiddle.net/j2nsg/2/

JS:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.values = ko.observableArray([{annotation:"blah2"}, {annotation:"blah4"}]);
}
$("#delete").click(function() {
    var removeMe = {annotation: "blah2"};
    model.values.remove(function(item) {
        return _.isEqual(item, removeMe); //this is just a deep equals between objects, actual code has far more complex stuff
    });
});

var model = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Menu">
    <p>Stuff In list:</p>
    <select id="resultsDb" data-bind="foreach:values">
        <option data-bind="text:annotation">
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<a href="javascript:null()" id="delete">delete</a>
```

All this does is populate an observable array in knockout, and provides a button to delete an element when clicked. However, if you click the button, the console displays an error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`. From a functionality standpoint, everything *appears* to work. Is there a way to fix this error (if it even is an error)?

Edit: Line for the error (for chrome) says VM994:1, (anonymous function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the attempt to call `null` which is not a function.  Instead of `javascript:null()` you can just use `#` or even leave the `href` off entirely.

Comment: Won't leaving the href off make it unclickable?

Comment: @KevinL no; it will still respond to the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `javascript:void(null)`

Either way you should be handling your click with knockout not jquery. Also, its generally better to not use an `a` element for buttons like that. You're better off using a `button`, or `span`.